# Does not load .Armodel file in camera only display white screen in kudan

Tags: ios, objective-c, kudan

i used xcode 8.0 and os version 9.3.5
when i use this demo i am unable to open camera.

first i put object this screen is work properly but when click done button than after display white screen.nothing display in this screen.

i used this Demo

https://github.com/kudan-eu/GPSSample-iOS

here is my screenshot
[image]

here is my code

mapViewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)progressButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.touchPin) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showGPSDemo" sender:self];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showGPSDemo"]) {
        // Set model coordinate to position of the map pin.
        CameraViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D touchPinCoordinate = self.touchPin.coordinate;

        viewController.objectCoordinate = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:touchPinCoordinate.latitude longitude:touchPinCoordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

CameraViewController.com

```
- (void)setupContent
{
    // Initialise and start the GPS Manager.
    ARGPSManager *gpsManager = [ARGPSManager getInstance];
    [gpsManager initialise];
    [gpsManager start];

    // Initialise a GPSNode with coordinate provided from the map.
    ARGPSNode *gpsNode = [[ARGPSNode alloc] initWithLocation:self.objectCoordinate];

    // Point the GPS Node due east.
    [gpsNode setBearing:90];

    // Must add GPSNode as a child to the GPS Manager world.
    [gpsManager.world addChild:gpsNode];

    // Import the model.
    ARModelImporter *modelImporter = [[ARModelImporter alloc] initWithBundled:@"bloodhound.armodel"];

    // The ARModel node represents all external contents relating to the model e.g.animations, textures.
    ARModelNode *modelNode = [modelImporter getNode];

    // Add the modelNode as a child to the GPSNode.
    [gpsNode addChild:modelNode];

    // Add the texture to the 3D model.
    ARTexture *modelTexture = [[ARTexture alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bloodhound.png"]];

    // Setup the object material.
    ARLightMaterial *modelMaterial = [[ARLightMaterial alloc] init];
    modelMaterial.colour.texture = modelTexture;
    modelMaterial.ambient.value = [ARVector3 vectorWithValuesX:0.5 y:0.5 z:0.5];
    modelMaterial.diffuse.value = [ARVector3 vectorWithValuesX:0.5 y:0.5 z:0.5];

    // Apply to the model.
    for (ARMeshNode *meshNode in modelNode.meshNodes) {
        meshNode.material = modelMaterial;
    }

    // Scale the model to the correct height of Big Ben from model height. Units of the GPSManager world are meters, model is 11008 units high in object space.
    [modelNode scaleByUniform:(96.0 / 11008.0)];

    self.gpsNode = gpsNode;
}
```

**here is my log**

```
Could not find file for texture Big_Ben_spec.png
2016-12-13 16:40:37.546 GPS Sample[13723:834618] RootNode ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:37.547 GPS Sample[13723:834618]   Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.001160, -0.000000, 0.001221)
2016-12-13 16:40:37.547 GPS Sample[13723:834618]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:37.547 GPS Sample[13723:834618]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:37.547 GPS Sample[13723:834618]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:37.547 GPS Sample[13723:834618]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:37.547 GPS Sample[13723:834618]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:39.877 GPS Sample[13723:834618] generated main fbo 2
2016-12-13 16:40:39.885 GPS Sample[13723:834618] created main FBO with width 1536 and height 2048
2016-12-13 16:40:40.281 GPS Sample[13723:834682] camera dimensions: 480.000000 x 640.000000
2016-12-13 16:40:40.282 GPS Sample[13723:834682] camera aspect ratio: 0.750000
2016-12-13 16:40:40.282 GPS Sample[13723:834682] framebuffer aspect ratio: 0.750000
2016-12-13 16:40:40.288 GPS Sample[13723:834682] rotating to orientation 1
2016-12-13 16:40:40.444 GPS Sample[13723:834682] WARNING: Could not find file for texture Big_Ben_diffuseShade.png
2016-12-13 16:40:40.444 GPS Sample[13723:834682] WARNING: Could not find file for texture Big_Ben_spec.png
2016-12-13 16:40:40.461 GPS Sample[13723:834682] RootNode ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:40.461 GPS Sample[13723:834682]   Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.001160, -0.000000, 0.001221)
2016-12-13 16:40:40.462 GPS Sample[13723:834682]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:40.462 GPS Sample[13723:834682]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:40.462 GPS Sample[13723:834682]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:40.462 GPS Sample[13723:834682]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:40.462 GPS Sample[13723:834682]     Big_Ben_001 ARVector3(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
2016-12-13 16:40:49.263 GPS Sample[13723:834618] Error while getting core location : (null)
```

Comment: Does Xcode log any errors to the console when it goes to load the view?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo i added my log

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the problem is that it can't get the GPS coordinates. I'm assuming it asked for permission to use your location and you said yes, so the only other explanation is that you didn't specify an actual location when the app started up. Did you tap the map and place a pin or just press "done" and go to the next screen?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo yes i place the pin than go to the next screen.but next screen display is total white screen see in my question i uploaded screenshot.pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used different ARAPIKey but finally i got right ARAPIKey

```
 [[ARAPIKey sharedInstance] setAPIKey:@"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"];
```

if this ARAPIKey is expired than get new key https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys